# Wordpress: eliminar funcion shortcode para enlaces descarga

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Hola tengo el tema [toroplay](https://torothemes.com/themes/toroplay/), en el que si trato de abrir mi enlace de descarga número 5 del post( digamos con ID 364), entonces el enlace saliente seria:

```
https://miweb.com/?trdownload=5&trid=364
```

y automaticamente hace redir para el enlace que inserte en la celda numero 5 de mi caja o zona de descarga cuando estoy relizando el post.

¿Alguien sabria como eliminar esa funcion `tr_download` para los enlaces de descarga y dejarlos directos?

Tengo ubicadas las funciones y archivos pero no logro hacerlo por mis propios medios.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: Si resolviste el problema planteado en la pregunta, realiza una respuesta en base a [answer], sería de mucha ayuda a la comunidad, saludos.